# Ping against IE - request timed out

Tags: .net, networking, webrequest

Where to look what could be a cause that "ping IP_address" returns "Request timed out", but opening "http://IP_address" in the Internet Explorer loads site correctly?

And in real impication: .NET making WebRequest to that IP works correctly on my machine, but does not work on clietn's.

I think there should be something with proxy, but not sure what should be done.
The .NET code is below:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl");
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: this is either a proxy and/or firewall and/or IDS and/or routing (backroute) issue... I have a customer where ping is blocked by firewall while http (via proxy) is allowed for users logged via domain... I don't think that you can anything... just make a traceroute and give the result to the IT admins...

Answer (score 2):

Some servers block `ping` requests.

Answer (score 0):

Some servers/ firewall/ gateway will block PING ( ICMP Request ), resulting in Request Timed Out; while loading a web page uses port 80 ( in most cases ), which is different than ICMP port .

**UPDATE:** According to your information given, you mentioned your codes WORK during debugging but does not work in a "Release" EXE, right? By default, during debugging session, the program bypasses most security settings.

Also, check Windows Firewall settings. Try disabling the Windows Firewall on client side & retry. If Windows Firewall is the culprit, add your program to Windows Firewall "Allowed Program" list and re-enable the Firewall.

Comment: Ok, for WebRequest.GetResponce() I also receive timeout exception, but it looks it uses port 80:

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 199.211.133.239:80